# Finding derivatives

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I'm not sure as to how to solve the following problem:

[image]

This is what I've done but no luck:

```
Solve[Dt[r Cos[θ]], Dt[x, θ]]
Solve[Dt[r Sin[θ]], Dt[y, θ]]
```

It gives no answer.

Answer (score 4):

Is this what you want? Does the r depent on Theta?

```
x[t_] = r[t] Cos[t]; y[t_] = r[t] Sin[t];

eqs = {x'[t] == 4 Sin[t] Cos[t] (Cos[t]^2 - Sin[t]^2), 
       y'[t] == 2 Sin[t]^2 (3 - 4 Sin[t]^2)}

eli = Eliminate[eqs, r[t]]

(*   (Cos[t]^2 + Sin[t]^2) Derivative[1][r][t] == 
      Sin[t] (4 Cos[t]^4 + 6 Sin[t]^2 - 4 Cos[t]^2 Sin[t]^2 - 8 Sin[t]^4)   *)

dsol = DSolve[eli, r, t]

(*   {{r -> Function[{t}, C[1] + Cos[t]/2 - 1/2 Cos[3 t]]}}   *)

sol = Solve[eqs /. First@dsol // Simplify, C[1]]

(*   {{C[1] -> 0}}   *)

rsol[t_] = r[t] /. First@dsol /. First@sol

(*   Cos[t]/2 - 1/2 Cos[3 t]   *)

Plot[rsol[t], {t, 0, 7}]

Plot[rsol'[t], {t, 0, 7}]

PolarPlot[rsol[t], {t, 0, 2 Pi}]

x[t] /. r -> rsol // Simplify

y[t] /. r -> rsol // Simplify

ParametricPlot[{x[t], y[t]} /. r -> rsol, {t, 0, 2 Pi}]
```